# What method calls `__init__()` in Python classes

Tags: python, class, methods

I was wondering how `__init__()` methods get called. Does `__new__()` calls it, or `__call__()` calls it after it created an instance with `__new__()`, or some other way?

Comment: You can take a look here: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html But in general __new__ called first while __init__ usually called right after instance created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python determines whether [__new__()](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) should call __init__():

> If __new__() returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s __init__() method will be invoked like __init__(self[, ...]), where self is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to __new__().

__init__() will *not* be called if __new__() is overridden and does not return an instance of the class.

[__call__()](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) is invoked when an instance object is called like a function:

```
class MyObj:
  def __call__():
    print 'Called!'

>>> mo = MyObj()
>>> mo()
Called!
```

And of course you can define __call__() with whatever arguments and logic you want.

Comment: More accurately, it's called implicitly by the Python runtime. You can write your own `__new__` that doesn't call `__init__` and it will still be called as long as you return an instance of the class.

Comment: True indeed!  Although this should be used with all due caution, as with most of Python's method overloading.

Comment: An important thing to note... Pythnon's runtime will call `__init__` *whenever* `__new__` returns an instance of `cls`, even if it's already been initialized (eg, is being returned from a cache); and it won't call `__init__` of any kind if the return value isn't an instance of `cls`.

Comment: You should really edit this. `__new__` doesn't call `__init__` as the docs and @Karl say, it's called automatically under certain circumstances.

Comment: Also, just wanted to note... the `__call__` that @yasar was probably referring to (though he didn't know it) is the `__call__` method of the *metaclass*, in this case `type`, of which `MyObj` is an instance. That's the one that gets called when you do `MyObj()`, and is what contains this logic.

Answer (score 3):

`__init__` is called at the instanciation of an object

```
http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__
```